# listchannels returns no results from CLN

Tags: lightning-network, core-lightning, p2p

CLN 0.12.1

My node has been running for hours now. But it doesn't seem to be aware of the network. This is what I get when I try to run listchannels.

```
$ lightning-cli listchannels
{
   "channels": []
}
```

What would cause this? And what can I do about it?

Comment: Do you have a connection to a peer in the network? Nodes gossip about the state of the network to learn about channels and nodes, but if you don't have a connection you won't get gossip.

Comment: https://lightning.readthedocs.io/lightning-listpeers.7.html

Comment: listpeers returns no results either. Would I use the connect command to make a connection without actually opening a channel? And if so, how would I find a peer?

Comment: @Zephyrus: I think the general advice would be to connect to a peer controlled by an individual/company that you know. But if you don't know anyone 1ml.com and amboss.space list Lightning nodes.

Comment: https://lightning.readthedocs.io/lightning-connect.7.html

Answer (score 1):

As cdecker points out in the comments, I think you are running a node where you do not have any connection with an external peer.

In fact core lightning is preservative, and it does not start to gossip information about yourself if you do not have any information to share.

Moreover, you can choose also to use the core lightning with only private channels so in this case, the network must not know your information!

So, I guess you want to use cln to make some analysis on the network? if yes you need to configure your cln and start to connect with some public peer.